# Bit shifting a floating-point

Tags: c++, bit, shift, fixed-point

I am working on a project of converting any real number into fixed point.

For example, the code below:

```cpp
float ff = 8.125f;
std::cout << std::bitset<32>(ff) << std::endl; //print binary fotmat
```

Output:

```
00000000000000000000000000001000
```

Only the integer part is printed out.

When I do:

```cpp
float ff = 8.125f;
int   va = ff * (1 << 8); //8bits shift left
    
std::cout << std::bitset<32>(va) << std::endl; //print binary fotmat
```

The output is:

```
00000000000000000000100000100000
```

Where the fraction part is printed out too.

I don't understand why.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [c++ bit shifting a float](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16908056/c-bit-shifting-a-float)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *Only the integer part is printed out.*

Well, of course, because that's all you've given the `bitset`: [there is no `std::bitset` constructor that takes a `float` argument](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset/bitset), so your `ff` is being converted to an `unsigned long long`, which will lose the fractional part (as any conversion of a floating-point type to an integral type will). Turning on compiler warnings will alert you to this; for example, for your first code snippet, the MSVC compiler shows:

> warning C4244: 'argument': conversion from 'float' to 'unsigned
> __int64', possible loss of data

In your second example, you are multiplying the `float` value by 256 and converting to the integer value, `2080` - which is what gets passed to the `bitset`.

If you want the *full* bitwise representation of your `float` variable in the `bitset`, you need to first copy that data into an `unsigned long long` variable and pass that to the constructor:

```cpp
    unsigned long long ffdata = 0;
    std::memcpy(&ffdata, &ff, sizeof(ff));
    std::cout << std::bitset<32>(ffdata) << std::endl;
```

Output:

```
01000001000000100000000000000000
```

Comment: oh my god, yes..i'm stupid! thank you~~~ very much