# What is the reason for "stack smashing detected"?

Tags: c++, pointers, casting, undefined-behavior

I am new to programming and am currently studying about address typecasting. I don't seem to understand why I am getting this : `*** stack smashing detected ***: terminated Aborted (core dumped)` when I run the following code??

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

void updateValue(int *p){
    *p = 610 % 255;
}

int main(){
    char ch = 'A';
    updateValue((int*)&ch);
    cout << ch; 
}
```

Here's what I understand about the code:

The address of `ch` is typecasted to `int*` and passed into the function `updateValue()`. Now, inside the `updateValue()` stack, an integer pointer `p` is created which points to `ch`. When p is dereferenced, it interprets `ch` as an `int` and reads 4(or 8) bytes of contiguous memory instead of 1. So, `'A'`(65) along with some garbage value gets assigned to `610%255` i.e. 20.

But I don't understand, what and where things are going wrong?

Comment: You have _undefined behavior_, anything can happen.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ can you please elaborate??

Comment: There's nothing to "elaborate". This behavior is undefined by the C++ standard. Anything can happen, from your program crashing, to running apparently without any problems, to your computer exploding in a fireball. Just because a C++ program compiles, and runs, doesn't mean that it will work correctly. C++ does not work this way. If a C++ program does something that's undefined by the C++ standard, you have no warranty as to what the results will be. The End.

Comment: You program is writing 4 bytes memory, you was owning only 1 byte of the 4 bytes written, so your program is literally overwriting memory that doesn't own. This action can cause any kind of problem. It can make crash the whole OS, only your program, or run with no apparent problem.

Comment: The C++ standard says *any behaviour* is allowed, so crashing with the error "stack smashing detected" is allowed.

Comment: "I am new to programming and am currently studying about address typecasting." The person teaching you is doing you a disservice. This kind of cast *should not* be taught.

Comment: @IkarusDeveloper `... so your program is literally overwriting memory that doesn't own...` that's a bit misleading, it does not matter if the program owns that memory or not. In the shown case the program might very well own that memory, but it might be just memory that something else of the program and that part becomes corrupted due to that.

Comment: @t.niese Yeah, A cleaner way of describe it would be that **your program is literally overwriting memory that its logic doesn't own**.
Prakhar if you still haven't a clear idea about what's causing your problem you may look at [this](https://onlinegdb.com/0SJgDChcW)

Comment: *What and where things are going wrong?*  C++ is not a nanny language.  It expects the programmer to not have ill-formed programs that cause **undefined behavior**.  So both the "what and where things are going wrong" is the programmer creating bad code, and compiling it.  In the olden days, we'd call this a PEBKAC (problem exists between keyboard and chair) error, or PICNIC (problem in chair, not in computer) error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The **problem** is that you're **typecasting** a `char*` to an `int*` and then dereferencing `p` which leads to **undefined behavior**.

> **Undefined behavior** means anything<sup>1</sup> can happen *including but not limited to* the program giving your expected output. But **never rely**(or make conclusions based) on the output of a program that has undefined behavior. The program may just crash.

So the output that you're seeing(maybe seeing) is a result of undefined behavior. And as i said **don't rely on the output** of a program that has UB. The program may just crash which happens in your case.

For example, [here](https://onlinegdb.com/Xy3jbzaci) the program crashes, but [here](https://wandbox.org/permlink/CqgNpR5DYNwzaOAE) it doesn't crash.

So the first step to make the program correct would be to remove UB. **Then and only then** you can start reasoning about the output of the program.

---

<sup><sup>1</sup>For a more technically accurate definition of undefined behavior see [this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub) where it is mentioned that: **there are no restrictions on the behavior of the program**.</sup>

Answer (score 7):

> when p is dereferenced, it interprets ...

When you indirect through the reinterpreted `p` and access an object of the wrong type, the behaviour of the program is undefined.

> what and where things are going wrong?

Things started going wrong when you reinterpreted a pointer to one type as a pointer to an unrelated type.

Some rules of thumb:

- Don't use reinterpret casts until you know what it does. They are difficult to get right, and are rarely useful.
- Don't use reinterpret casts when it would result in undefined behaviour.
- Don't use C-style casts at all.
- If you think that you need to reinterpret cast, then take a few steps back, and consider *why* you think that you need it.

Answer (score 3):

> But I don't understand, what and where things are going wrong?

In this statement

```
*p = 610 % 255;
```

the memory that does not belong to the object ch that has the type char is overwritten. That is instead of one byte occupied by the object ch there are overwritten 4 bytes that correspond to the allocated memory for an object of the type int.